# How do I display correct address type based on state code found in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to display Party address as non-standard or standard or Foreign address based on the CaseParty/State or Party/State found in the in the xml document. 
In my xsl I have already checked for the State in the referring xsd document. 
If the State is not found in the two referring documents, I would like to display the party address as foreign address.
My code is not displaying foreign address as foreign which has a different format as I have shown in the desired output.

Desired output

```
<nc:Address>
        <nc:AddressFullText>123 Mexico RD Cancun, MM, 12345 Mexico</nc:AddressFullText>
    </nc:Address>
```

Wrong output

```
<nc:Address>
        <nc:LocationStreet>
            <nc:StreetNumberText>123</nc:StreetNumberText>
            <nc:StreetPredirectionalText/>
            <nc:StreetName>Mexico</nc:StreetName>
            <nc:StreetCategoryText>Road</nc:StreetCategoryText>
            <nc:StreetPostdirectionalText/>
            <nc:StreetExtensionText/>
        </nc:LocationStreet>
        <nc:LocationCityName>Cancun</nc:LocationCityName>
        <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>MM</nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
        <nc:LocationPostalCode>12345</nc:LocationPostalCode>
    </nc:Address>
```

My xml document

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67084884" xmlns="">

<Party ID="16770378" InternalPartyID="1614673416">
    <NotifyElectronically>0</NotifyElectronically>
    <PartyInJailFlag>false</PartyInJailFlag>
    <DateOfBirth Current="true">05/31/1960</DateOfBirth>
    <Address PartyCorrespondence="true" PartyCurrent="true" ID="17875835" Type="Standard">
        <AddressLine2>123 Mexico RD</AddressLine2>
        <AddressLine4>Cancun, MM, 12345</AddressLine4>
        <Block>123</Block>
        <Street>Mexico</Street>
        <AddrSfxKy Word="RD">Road</AddrSfxKy>
        <City>Cancun</City>
        <State>MM</State>
        <Zip>12345</Zip>
        <Foreign>false</Foreign>
        <TimestampCreate>5/28/2015 10:31:50 AM</TimestampCreate>
    </Address>
</Party>
</Integration>
```

Sample referring usps_states.xsd document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:structures="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:appinfo="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/" xmlns:usps-3.0.1="http://publication.niem.gov/niem/codes/usps_states/3.0/1/" xmlns:ct="http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://publication.niem.gov/niem/codes/usps_states/3.0/1/" version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/ ../../../../appinfo/3.0/appinfo.xsd http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/ ../../../../conformanceTargets/3.0/conformanceTargets.xsd" ct:conformanceTargets="http://reference.niem.gov/niem/specification/naming-and-design-rules/3.0/#ReferenceSchemaDocument">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>U.S. Postal Service Supplement</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:import namespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" schemaLocation="../../../../structures/3.0/structures.xsd"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="USStateCodeSimpleType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A data type for states.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="AK">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>ALASKA</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="AR">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>ARKANSAS</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Sample referring post-canada.xsd document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:structures="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:appinfo="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/" xmlns:can="http://release.niem.gov/niem/codes/canada_post/3.0/" xmlns:ct="http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/codes/canada_post/3.0/" version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://release.niem.gov/niem/appinfo/3.0/ ../../../appinfo/3.0/appinfo.xsd http://release.niem.gov/niem/conformanceTargets/3.0/ ../../../conformanceTargets/3.0/conformanceTargets.xsd" ct:conformanceTargets="http://reference.niem.gov/niem/specification/naming-and-design-rules/3.0/#ReferenceSchemaDocument">
    <xs:import namespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/" schemaLocation="../../../structures/3.0/structures.xsd"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="CanadianProvinceCodeSimpleType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="BC">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>British Columbia</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="MB">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Manitoba</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="NB">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>New Brunswick</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

My xsl code

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Party[@ID=current()/@ID]/Address[@PartyCurrent='true']">
                    <xsl:call-template name="Address"/>
                </xsl:for-each>

<--Address Template-->

        <xsl:template name="Address">
        <xsl:variable name="vUsState">
            <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\NiemExchanges\DvsDriverLicenseNotification\niem\codes\usps_states\3.0\1\usps_states.xsd'))/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vCanadianState">
            <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\NiemExchanges\DvsDriverLicenseNotification\niem\codes\canada_post\3.0\post-canada.xsd'))/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <nc:Address>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Block and string-length($vUsState or $vCanadianState)>0">
    <!--Standard-->
                    <nc:LocationStreet>
                        <nc:StreetNumberText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Block"/>
                        </nc:StreetNumberText>
                        <nc:StreetPredirectionalText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="PreDir"/>
                        </nc:StreetPredirectionalText>
                        <nc:StreetName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Street"/>
                        </nc:StreetName>
                        <nc:StreetCategoryText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="AddrSfxKy"/>
                        </nc:StreetCategoryText>
                        <nc:StreetPostdirectionalText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="PostDir"/>
                        </nc:StreetPostdirectionalText>
                        <nc:StreetExtensionText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(UnitKy, ' ' , UnitNum))"/>
                        </nc:StreetExtensionText>
                    </nc:LocationStreet>
                    <nc:LocationCityName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
                    </nc:LocationCityName>
                    <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
                    </nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                    <nc:LocationPostalCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/>
                    </nc:LocationPostalCode>
                </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Foreign ='false'">
    <!--Non-Standard-->
                        <nc:LocationStreet>
                            <nc:StreetFullText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
                            </nc:StreetFullText>
                            <nc:StreetFullText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine2"/>
                            </nc:StreetFullText>
                            <nc:StreetFullText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine3"/>
                            </nc:StreetFullText>
                        </nc:LocationStreet>
                        <nc:LocationCityName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
                        </nc:LocationCityName>
                        <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="State"/>
                        </nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                        <nc:LocationPostalCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/>
                        </nc:LocationPostalCode>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
    <!--Foreign-->
                        <nc:AddressFullText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine1, '&#xa;')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine2, '&#xa;')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine3, '&#xa;')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressLine4, '&#xa;')"/>
                        </nc:AddressFullText>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </nc:Address>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem you have is with this line

```
<xsl:when test="Block and string-length($vUsState or $vCanadianState)>0">
```

Where you do `$vUsState or $vCanadianState`, then this is a boolean expression, that will return either true or false. Therefore the string-length will always be greater than 0. What your probably should do is this:

```
<xsl:when test="Block and ($vUsState or $vCanadianState)">
```

However, you might find this still doesn't work as expected. The problem in this case is how you have defined the two variables

```
    <xsl:variable name="vUsState">
        <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\Schemas\NiemExchanges\DvsDriverLicenseNotification\niem\codes\usps_states\3.0\1\usps_states.xsd'))/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

By using `xsl:value-of` here, you are creating a result-tree fragment (I am assuming you are using XSLT 1.0 here) which means the variable itself will not be "empty". It will be a fragment containing an empty string. Therefore doing `$vUsState or $vCanadianState` is always going to return true. What you need to do is change your definitions to this, to reference the attribute directly, rather than create a copy

```
  <xsl:variable name="vUsState" select="document('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\usps_states.xsd')/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
```

This means it will be empty if the attribute does not exist, and so the expression `$vUsState or $vCanadianState` will return false if neither contain the state

Try this (abridged) XSLT as starters

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:nc="nc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Party/Address[@PartyCurrent='true']">
      <xsl:call-template name="Address"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Address">
    <xsl:variable name="vUsState" select="document('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\usps_states.xsd')/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vCanadianState" select="document('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\post-canada.xsd')/xs:schema/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value=current()/State]/@value"/>
    <nc:Address>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Block and ($vUsState or $vCanadianState)">
          <Standard />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Foreign ='false'">
          <NonStandard />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <Foreign />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </nc:Address>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that for your given input XML, the `Foreign` element is set to `false`, meaning the second `xsl:when` clause will apply, and so you will get the second address form in this case.

Comment: Oh wow Tim. I just like the way you in detail explained why or why not my code would not work. Your answers are always the best. You always explain the reasoning behind your suggested solution to the code problem. You must not only be an expert, you are also a teacher. Thanks again.